# Gertboard to control 4 servos?

Tags: gpio, servo, gertboard

I have been given this arm:

[image: Imgur]

It consists of 4 servos, which need to be controlled individually.

Can I control them using [Gertboard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11773)? Gertboard has only one motor driver, but it also has several open collector ports and buffered outputs.

I know Raspberry Pi itself can control a servo through a PWM pin and that you can emulate PWM on any additional pins. How do I do it safely via Gertboard? Should I use buffered pins? Won't servos blow my Pi or Gertboard up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a servo control wire direct to a Pi gpio and use hardware timed PWM to control the servo position.  You could have an in-line resistor if you prefer (say 1K-10K).

I don't know if you can generate reliable PWM on a Gertboard.  Software timed PWM is unlikely to give satisfactory control of servos.  That said, there is little harm in trying, at worse you will shorten the servo's life a little.

Comment: So a servo can't damage the computer like DC motors can? Will the resistor prevent any damage?

Comment: A resistor may help prevent damage if you wire it incorrectly, i.e. connect to 5V when you meant to connect to the control wire.  I don't use them myself.  Frankly they might cause more problems then they solve as far as the servo control wire is concerned.  Servos have in-built motor driver boards.  Motors don't.  You should always control motors via a motor driver board or motor driver chip.  Again, I don't use resistors between the gpios and the motor driver board.